# This field cannot be set - Terraform custom provider

Tags: terraform

I am newbie for creating the custom provider to terraform. I am trying to get some values from tf files. But I am gettings some errors.

```
Error: "tags": this field cannot be set
```

Here is my sample code

main.tf

```
# This is required for Terraform 0.13+
terraform {
  required_providers {
    example = {
      version = "~> 1.0.0"
      source  = "example.com/sd/example"
    }
  }
}
resource "example_server" "my-server" {
  address = "1.2.3.4"

  sensitive_map {
      key   = "foo"
      value = "dddd"
  }

  tags = {
      env = "development"
      name = "example tag"
  }
}
```

Here is my resource provider file.

```
func resourceServer() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        Create: resourceServerCreate,
        Read:   resourceServerRead,
        Update: resourceServerUpdate,
        Delete: resourceServerDelete,
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "address": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
            },
            "tags": {
                Type: schema.TypeMap,
                Elem: &schema.Schema{
                    Type: schema.TypeString,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}

func resourceServerCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) error {
    logs.Info("Creating word")
    address := d.Get("address").(string)
    // tags := d.Get("tags").(interface{})
    // keyval := tags.(map[string]interface{})

    d.SetId(address)
    log.Printf("[WARN] No Server found: %s", d.Id())
    f, err := os.OpenFile("/home/sdfd/Desktop/123.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()


    tmps := d.Get("tags").(map[string]interface{})
    address += tmps["env"].(string)
    address += tmps["name"].(string)

    if _, err = f.WriteString(address); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am not able to find the exact error. Logs also not printing in the terminal. Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That could be a red herring. `sensitive_map` is not defined in your schema. Try to remove your `sensitive_map` argument from the config and see if that resolves the error. If it does, I can write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `schema.Schema` object used to define an attribute or nested block must *always* have at least one of `Required: true`, `Optional: true`, or `Computed: true` set.

`Required` and `Optional` both indicate that the argument is one that can be set in the configuration. Since you've set neither of them for `tags`, the SDK is rejecting attempts to set `tags` in the configuration.

`Computed` indicates that the provider itself will be the one to decide the value. This can either be used alone or in conjunction with `Optional`. If you set both `Optional` *and* `Computed` then that means that the provider will provide its own value if (and only if) the user leaves it unset in the configuration.

Since it seems like your intent here is for `tags` to be set by the user in the configuration, I think the answer here would be to mark it as `Optional`:

```
            "tags": {
                Type: schema.TypeMap,
                Elem: &schema.Schema{
                    Type: schema.TypeString,
                },
                Optional: true,
            },
```

The above means that it *may* be set in the configuration, but the user isn't required to set it. If the user doesn't set it then your provider code will see it as the built-in default placeholder value for a map, which is an empty map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working as expected